# Android: Fragment tab host showing text for tab but not icon

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, fragment-tab-host

I am using a tabhost to hold and navigate multiple fragments. I am not sure what I am doing wrong but the tab is only showing the text but not the icon (I really only need the icon and no text). Fragment 1 and 2 tabs are setup to only show text but on the third fragment tab I try to add in the icon with `getDrawable`. There is no error everything compiles fine but it just doesn't show the icon.

Thanks for your help.

This is the start of my `oncreateView` method where I set the tabs up:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_discovered_songs, container, false);


    mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("fragment1").setIndicator("Fragment 1"),
            OneFragment.class, null);

    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("fragment2").setIndicator("Fragment 2"),
            TwoFragment.class, null);

    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("fragment3").setIndicator("Fragment 3", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.com_facebook_button_icon)),
            ThreeFragment.class, null);
```

Comment: go through this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JJeeZHFgLfc

Comment: visit this link here you get all the thing : http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/

Comment: Thanks for your response but none of these links relate to a tabhost which is my question. I have a fragment containing three other fragments in a tabhost. Whereas the links you have posted are an activity that that has 3 fragments.